# Linux: synchronize directories via symlinks

Tags: linux, rsync, symlink

I have two directories, say `A/` and `B/`, each with their own subtree. I'd need to synchronize the content of `A/` with the content of `B/`. 
The result I need is similar to recursively copying the subtree of `B/` into `A/` with `cp -r`, except that instead of actually copying the data from `B/`, I want to create symlinks in `A/` which point to the files in `B/`.

My question is, is there a simple way/command/tool to do this or I have to create `B/`'s subtree in `A/` and then go over all `B/`s files and create the symlinks? The best would be to be able to use `rsync` as a symlink creator and then just the delta symlinks would be created, but I don't think this is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With 2 commands you could achive this: here is an example to clone directory structure of `/etc` and create symlinks for all files in `/etc`:

```
# create directories
find /etc -type d -exec mkdir .{} \;

# symlink files
find /etc -type f -exec ln -s {} .{} \;
```

Comment: any chance to speed up the process and only create the symlink that are not already there? `B/` is constantly changing and I need to update the symlinks in `A/` from time to time, accordingly. Could you think of any method to update the symlinks incrementally, like `rsync` would do with the files?